# i can't get array b of object a with reduce in js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i can't get array b of object a with reduce in js

can you help me find the error?

```
const a = {
  dias:"valor",
  horas:"valor"
}

const b = campos.reduce((acc, el) => ([...acc, {
  title: el, field: el
}]), {})

desired result = [
 { title: 'dias', field: 'dias' },
 { title: 'horas', field: 'horas' },
]
```

Comment: be careful with the array name is a=campos

Comment: You can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66351108/edit) your question to fix typos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys).

```js
const a = {
  dias: "valor",
  horas: "valor",
};

const b = Object.keys(a).map((key) => ({ title: key, field: key }));

console.log(b);
```

If you want the value of the property as the field instead, you can use [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries):

```js
const a = {
  dias: "valor",
  horas: "valor",
};

const b = Object.entries(a).map(([key, value]) => ({
  title: key,
  field: value,
}));

console.log(b);
```

As a note, the `[key, value]` syntax is called [array destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).